# How to add multiple cc email address using phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to add multiple email address in phpmailer AddCC().

With below code i am able to add only one email address in cc. But i want to add all the emails fetched from the query.

```
$sqlcc = "SELECT * FROM notificationslist WHERE status='1'";
$querycc = $connect->query($sqlcc);

$num_rowscc = mysqli_num_rows($querycc);


if($num_rowscc>0){

    while ($row = $querycc->fetch_assoc()) {
        $ccemail= $row['email'];
        $ccname= $row['employee'];
    }
} else {
   $ccemail= 'akash1sethi@gmail.com';
   $ccname= 'Akash Sethi';
}
```

***PHP MAILER CODE HERE***

```
$multiplecc = array(
    $ccemail => $ccname,
    );


foreach ($multiplecc as $ccemail => $ccname)
{
    $mail->AddCC(trim($ccemail), $ccname);
}
```

Comment: your approach is valid, are you sure the values added are correct? how many are you trying to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array to store multiple cc emails.

```
while ($row = $querycc->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ccemail[]= $row['email'];
    $ccname[]= $row['employee'];
}
```

And these arrays in phpmailer code.

Or you can use the below code.

```
if($num_rowscc>0){
    while ($row = $querycc->fetch_assoc()) {
        // create an array to have multiple records
        $recipients[]= array('email'=>$row['email'],'name'=>$row['employee']);
    }
} else {
   $recipients[]= array('email'=>'akash1sethi@gmail.com','name'=>'Akash Sethi');
}
```

In phpmailer

```
// loop the array and add to cc
foreach($recipients as $recipient){
   $mail->AddCC($recipient['email'],$recipient['name']);
}
```

Comment: @rtfm  in the while loop he is not creating array, he is assigning values directly to variables, which will have only last results.